# Symfony non-compound form options on-the-fly change by form events?

Tags: php, forms, events, dynamic, symfony

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347892/acting-on-a-symfony-parent-form-from-child-event-for-adding-new-type) relative to a specific problem I would like to generalize in following different question :

> Is it possible to change options (i.e. "choices" attribute) on an
>   non-compound form (i.e. EntityType) by events listeners ?

My diggings into Forms, particularly on PRE_SET_DATA and POST_SET_DATA events, seemed to reveal 2 things :

- As their names suggest, the are data-focused events. Although you can act on form by adding/updating/removing children, it seems to be irrelevant in my very case (non-compound form). Furthermore, this is what I tried to do on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347892/acting-on-a-symfony-parent-form-from-child-event-for-adding-new-type) without success.
- I didn't catch any other event in the builder part, where options are parsed where I could hook onto in order to make my change.

Simple example I would like to achieve : change choices for an EntityType without having to define logic while calling `$builder->add('myType', EntityTpe::class, $options);`.

Many thanks for your leads, tricks or suggestions. I think I miss a major design point on this one.

Nicolas